# Knowing the number of users with a group policy aplied

Tags: group-policy

The question is pretty simple. Is there any way to get the number of users on an Active Directory with a specific Group policy applied?

For example, i need to know how many users has the strong password policy applied and i can't access computer by computer to check it.

Comment: If you have to ask, the answer is probably `all of them` or `none of them`.  There's a lot of confusion around fine-grained password policies, and most organizations that *thought* they were setting different password policies for different groups weren't actually doing so.

Comment: The question is: the admin sais something and i need to prove if the statement is correcto so, i need to check on an LDAP query or something like that

Answer (score 3):

I'll address this in two sections, since password policies are handled differently than most other GPO settings.

---

> For example, i need to know how many users has the strong password policy applied and i can't access computer by computer to check it.

If you're not using Fine Grained Password Policies, then *all* of your users will have the same password policy.

If you are using Fine Grained Password Policies, then you have to define a specific user or group to apply that policy to, so just count who is in that group.

You can use a combination of `Get-ADGroupMember` and `Measure-Object` in PowerShell if there are too many to count by hand or you want to automate it, for some reason.

---

> Is there any way to get the number of users on an Active Directory with a specific Group policy applied?

Group policies apply to users or computers and are linked to domains, sites, and OUs. Simple check where the the policy that you're curious about is linked to, and then count everything that it applies to within that domain, site, or OU. The `Measure-Object` PowerShell cmdlet is your friend here.

Comment: For the latter question, he'll also need to account for any blocked inheritance (resets to 0 so start from a fresh slate as you descend) or WMI filtering, which might be somewhat tough. Also, any "read deny" permissions on any individual GPO would prevent them from applying as well, to the users/groups being denied.

Comment: @mfinni All very true. Maybe I should shorten the answer to "Figure out what the GPO is applying to and count" :)

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for the responses. I'm auditing an active directory so i need to check every time the users with the policies applied. Isn't there any other way to automatically check?

Comment: You can monitor the event logs on all of the machines

Comment: sure @MDMarra but we license the SIEM solution by machine monitored so, it's too much expensive. I've found GPInventory but i'm not sure if it works with WS2008 AD